# How to use #define mask in "if" comparison

Tags: c

I've defined in one header file two #define with a mask:

**myheader.h**

```
#define MASK_A IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666
#define MASK_B 0666

void myfunction(int mymask);
```

**myfile.c**

```
#include "myheader.h" 

... 

void myfunction(int mymask) {
   if (MASK_A == mymask) {
      printf("My mask is A\n");
      /* Do some things... */   
   } else {
      printf("My mask is B\n");
      /* Do other things...*/   
   } 
}

void main() {   

    myfunction(MASK_A);
    myfunction(MASK_B); 
}
```

As far as I know, with this simple program should do first MASK_A things defined in `myfunction`and  after that, MASK_B things, but I don't know why, **both times program goes through MASK_A way**.

> Cast `if ((int)MASK_A == mymask)` doesn't work.
>
> It looks like #define MASK_A and MASK_B are not being considered as integer, because:

If I redefine function as:

```
void myfunction(int mymask) {
   int _maskA=MASK_A;
   if (_maskA == mymask) {
      printf("My mask is A\n");
      /* Do some things... */   
   } else {
      printf("My mask is B\n");
      /* Do other things...*/   
   } 
}
```

It works fine, but it doesn't look very pretty.
Anyone knows a better way to manage `#define` literals and integer comparison, please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should write `#define MASK_A (IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666)`

Comment: That's why MISRA rule 19.4 says that a macro should only expand to a braced initialisier, a constant ....and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work because Comparison operator (==) has Higher precedence than Bitwise Or (|).
So when you do

```
 if (MASK_A == mymask)
```

it results into,

```
if (IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666==mymask)
```

final execution is somewhat like,

```
if (IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL |( 0666==mymask))
```

Try defining your macro as

```
#define MASK_A (IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is advised to *always* parenthesise your macros

```
#define MASK_A (IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666)
```

Especially when it comes to `&` and `|`, C's precedence rules
can be confusing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
int main()
{
    int mask = 0xAA|0xBB00; assert(mask==0xBBAA);

    printf("%x\n", 0xAA|0xBB00 == mask);
    //prints aa because 0xAA|(0xBB00==mask /*false==0*/)  equals 0xAA
    //IOW, == has a higher precedence than |  
    //ans so 0xAA|0xBB00==mask is equivalent to 0xAA|(0xBB00==mask) 

    printf("%x\n", (0xAA|0xBB00) == mask);
    //prints 1 — parentheses force the intended grouping
}
```

As Denis Ritchie, the language's author, put it in the first K&R,

> ["Some of the operators have the wrong precedence; some parts of the
>   syntax could be better."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_(programming_language)#cite_note-22)

He explains these precedences for `|` and `&` in his article, 
[The Development of the C Language*](http://The%20Development%20of%20the%20C%20Language) where he explains that 
`|` and `&` were used in `B` instead of the short-circuiting, logical `||` and `&&` (which B didn't have and neither did prehistoric C) and so the precedence rules for `|` and `&` were so that:

```
  if (a==b & c)
```

would be parsed as

```
 if ((a==b) & c)
```

The short-circuting, logical `&&` and `||` were later added, but the original precedences for `|` and `&` were kept.

Answer (score 1):

It is a known flaw in the C language that `|` and `&` have lower precedence than `==` (Dennis Ritchie admitted this at some point). This is the practical reason why your code doesn't work.

Solve this by writing the macro properly:

```
#define MASK_A (IPC_CREAT | IPC_EXCL | 0666)
```

Any decent C programming book will address issues like this and show how to write macros properly with parenthesis.

Comment: Perfect experience but inadequate explanation.

Comment: @snr Feel free to post an answer of your own, or perhaps hunt down a duplicate.